# How To convert array in string like to concate string with first array word like array[0].'->'.array[1]

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, concatenation

```
$arr = ['Governance->Policies->Prescriptions->CAS Alerts',
        'Users->User Departments->Department Hierarchy',
        'Settings->Registrar->Finance',
        'Logs->Second Opinion Log'];
```

This is array and I want to convert it into string like below
The string should be one it just concate in one string.

```
Governance->Policies
Governance->Prescriptions
Governance->CAS Alerts

Users->User Departments
Users->Department Hierarchy

Settings->Registrar
Settings->Finance

Logs->Second Opinion Log
```

```
$arr = ['Governance->Policies->Prescriptions->CAS Alerts',
        'Users->User Departments->Department Hierarchy',
        'Settings->Registrar->Finance',
        'Logs->Second Opinion Log'];
$temp = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $arrVal = [];
    
    $arrVal = explode('->',$arr[$i]);
    if(count($arrVal) > 1){
        for($j=0; $j < count($arrVal); $j++){
            if($j == 0){
                $temp .= $arrVal[$j];
            }else{
                $temp .='->'.$arrVal[$j]."\n";
                if($j == count($arrVal) - 1){
                    $temp .= "\n";
                }else{
                    $temp .= substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, "->"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
 } 
 echo $temp;
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please describe what problem you're having, and why your attempted code didn't work (faulty output, error messages, etc). Also, I strongly recommend using `foreach` to make your code easier to read.

Comment: Yeah from my attempted code I am getting the result but but somehow looping condition it display wrong firsrt loop data come right but in second it giving wrong.

Comment: Edit your question to show the output you get. Please don't use comments to add missing details.

Comment: Why you don't use array multidimensional ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

```php
<?php
//This might help full
$arr = ['Governance->Policies->Prescriptions->CAS Alerts',
        'Users->User Departments->Department Hierarchy',
        'Settings->Registrar->Finance',
        'Logs->Second Opinion Log'];
        
$result="";
$newline="<br>";
foreach($arr as $data){
    $wordlist=explode('->',$data);
    $firstword=$wordlist[0];
    $temp='';
    foreach($wordlist  as $key=>$value){
      if($key > 0){
        $temp.=$firstword."->".$value.$newline;
      }
    }
    $temp.=$newline;
    $result.=$temp;
}
echo $result;
?>
```

`Output :`

```
Governance->Policies
Governance->Prescriptions
Governance->CAS Alerts

Users->User Departments
Users->Department Hierarchy

Settings->Registrar
Settings->Finance

Logs->Second Opinion Log
```

Comment: Use array slice to skip the first element. Don't check for key 0 on each and every iteration.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As you iterate your array of arrow-delimited strings, explode each element on its arrows, separate the the first value from the rest, then iterate the remaining elements from the explosion and prepend the cached, first value and push into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QIIYH))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $string) {
    $parts = explode('->', $string);
    $parent = array_shift($parts);
    foreach ($parts as $child) {
        $result[] = "{$parent}->$child";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Easily the better answer here. Is `echo join('<br>', $result)` reasonable for the output? Does the inner FOREACH have an overhead compared to using JOIN "as" the inner loop? (I'm no php coder, but most high level or interpretted languages benefit from the low level loop implementations in JOIN, etc)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/eInKU ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['Governance->Policies->Prescriptions->CAS Alerts',
        'Users->User Departments->Department Hierarchy',
        'Settings->Registrar->Finance',
        'Logs->Second Opinion Log'];

foreach ($arr as $path) {
  $path_elements = explode('->', $path);
  if (count($path_elements) > 1) {
    $path_head = $path_elements[0];
    $path_tail = array_slice($path_elements, 1);
    foreach ($path_tail as $path_item) {
      echo $path_head, '->', $path_item, "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";  
  }
}
```

Demo : https://onlinephp.io/c/9eb2d

Or, using JOIN()

```
$arr = ['Governance->Policies->Prescriptions->CAS Alerts',
        'Users->User Departments->Department Hierarchy',
        'Settings->Registrar->Finance',
        'Logs->Second Opinion Log'];

foreach ($arr as $path) {
  $path_elements = explode('->', $path);
  if (count($path_elements) > 1) {
    $path_head = $path_elements[0];
    $path_tail = array_slice($path_elements, 1);
    echo
      $path_head,
      '->',
      join('<br>'. $path_head.'->',$path_tail),
      '<br><br>';
  }
}
```

Demo : https://onlinephp.io/c/c1826

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yup, that's the price of my answering from bed ;) (Feel free to down vote, I'm not precious about rep)